# Как собрать в список последние элементы списка списков сгрупировав их по другим элементам?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Есть список со списками, максимальное количество элементов в списке 3:

```
inp = [
    ['A1', 'B1', 'A1'],
    ['A1', 'B1', 'A2'],
    ['A1', 'B1', 'A3'],
    ['A1', 'B2', 'A4'],
    ['A1', 'B2', 'A5'],
    ['A2', 'B1', 'A6'],
    ['A2', 'B1', 'A7']
]
```

Первый и второй элемент списка часто дублируется, а 3й элемент разный.

Надо, чтобы первый и второй элемент списка не дублировались, а третьи элементы собирались в список.

В результате должен получиться вот такой список списков:

```
out = [
    ['A1', 'B1', ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']],
    ['A1', 'B2', ['A4', 'A5']],
    ['A2', 'B1', ['A6', 'A7']]
]
```

Не понимаю, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Вариант 1** - используем [itertools.groupby(...)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

inp = [
    ['A1', 'B1', 'A1'],
    ['A1', 'B1', 'A2'],
    ['A1', 'B1', 'A3'],
    ['A1', 'B2', 'A4'],
    ['A1', 'B2', 'A5'],
    ['A2', 'B1', 'A6'],
    ['A2', 'B1', 'A7']
]

res = [[k[0], k[1], [t[2] for t in c]] 
        for k,c in groupby(sorted(inp), key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))]

print(res)
```

результат

```
[['A1', 'B1', ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']],
 ['A1', 'B2', ['A4', 'A5']],
 ['A2', 'B1', ['A6', 'A7']]]
```

**Вариант 2** - используем модуль Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd  # pip install pandas

df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
res = df.groupby([0,1])[2].apply(list).reset_index().to_numpy().tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сгруппировать с помощью словаря, используя кортеж со значениями первых двух столбцов в качестве ключа.

```
inp = [ 
    ['A1', 'B1', 'A1'],
    ['A1', 'B1', 'A2'],
    ['A1', 'B1', 'A3'],
    ['A1', 'B2', 'A4'],
    ['A1', 'B2', 'A5'],
    ['A2', 'B1', 'A6'],
    ['A2', 'B1', 'A7']
]

dct = {}

for *first_two_cols, third in inp:
    key = tuple(first_two_cols)
    dct.setdefault(key, []) 
    dct[key].append(third)

# Переводим словарь в список.
out = [[*first_two_cols, third] for first_two_cols, third in dct.items()]
# Или так
#out = [[first, second, third] for (first, second), third in dct.items()]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)
```

**Результат**

```
[['A1', 'B1', ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']],
 ['A1', 'B2', ['A4', 'A5']],
 ['A2', 'B1', ['A6', 'A7']]]
```